# how to split address field to street type, street name, number, etc?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ssis

Im developing a web application in c #. Net to standardize street addresses. What I need to do now is the following:
In a database sql server 2005 I have 3 tables:

```
1. - Street address that need split, which contains hundreds of addresses
like this:  | streetType stretName number other | all in a same
field.

 2. - All street names of the country, separated by city.

 3. - All street types, example: avenue, street, road, etc.
```

The result of the division I need to get is:

```
street type | stret name | number | other
```

With sql server, ssis or c #. Net how I can get this result?

In sql server:
Table 1 (in) street address to normalize- fields:

- id (int aut)
- Street address all in a field (varchar)

Table 2 (out) normalized address split in fields

- street type (varchar) (example: avenue, road, street, etc)
- street name (varchar)
- street number
- others

Here its an example

here is an example in excel. It consists of 3 sheets:

```
1. Table address to normalize: Addresses are stored in sql server 2005
I need to normalize. 
2. Table street name by city They are all street names in the country, separated by city. With this normalized direction.
3. - Table street types These are the types of existing street.
```

The tables have sample records. 
I just need to split the field, because I can already normalized
Here its an example with records
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=182141CD87872379!1701
Thanks!!

Comment: Sample input and expected output for the same?

Comment: What is wrong w/ `streetType stretName number other".Split(' ');`?

Comment: Sriam Sakthivel, added information input / output expected. Thank you!

Comment: paqogomez i dont understand??

Comment: I asked for sample but you added table structure. Sample means show one entry from your database or similar one. and what output you expect

Comment: I strongly suggest you acquire a service for address standardization.  Each country has their own rules fir how addresses should be normalized/ cleansed

Comment: Reason why I ask sample is it may differ. there may be consisteny ` ` char as seperator or etc. If nothing is conststent we can't split data. So providing 3 or 4 different inputs will be better

Comment: Im doing a example, in a few minutes finish. Thank you very much!

Comment: here is an example in excel. It consists of 3 sheets:
1. - Table address to normalize:
Addresses are stored in sql server 2005 I need to normalize
2. - Table street name by city
They are all street names in the country, separated by city. With this normalized direction.
3. - Table street types
These are the types of existing street

The tables have sample records.

Mind you, I just need to split the field, because I can already normalized.

Comment: Here is the link example          https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=182141CD87872379!1701

Answer (score 0):

You have several options for trying to parse addresses:

1. Custom T-SQL commands: The upside is you could do this today with your code.  It would take a lot of CHARINDEX, PATINDEX, and SUBSTRING commands wrapped in a CASE statement.  The downside is that you may not identify all patterns correctly and may introduce errors.  Also, if you have global addresses, then there are likely many different patterns of addresses and you will likely make numerous mistakes.
2. [CozyRoc Address Parse](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/address-parse) for SSIS: If you are only parsing US addresses, then this is a good solution.  The upside is that you don't have to write the parsing code.  The downside is that this costs money and ONLY works for US addresses.  I have used this product myself, so I can say it worked well for my purposes.
3. Other 3rd Party Address Parsers: There are many other address parsers than just CozyRoc.  I haven't used any of them, but I am sure they are many that are just as good or better.

Comment: I think I used the first option.
you'll have some example? considering that I have all street names and all kinds of street?